# Позиционирование элементов по столбцам в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 3 TextBox "в столбик", нужно, чтобы их было 6 (3 столбца)

Вопрос: как организовать второй и третий столбик, чтобы расстояние между каждым было 20px?

```
<StackPanel>
    <!--First Colomn-->
    <Border Padding="20 120 630 290">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Padding="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border Padding="20 150 630 260">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Padding="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border Padding="20 180 630 230">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Padding="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `Padding="20 120 630 290"` - не когда не передвигайте элементы руками, пишите эти цифры сами (иначе в скором времени будете задавать вопросы "почему я не вижу элемент" или "у меня скачет вся разметка"). Не должно быть как по мне выше 10-20 отступов. А по вопросу - используйте `Grid`, создавайте в нем сколько вашей душе угодно столбиков и размещайте элементы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ почему не как ответ? ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Как скажете)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте для начала пройдёмся по тому, что вы написали, ваша разметка...

1. У вас очень много лишних элементов. Вы делаете `<StackPanel>`, в ней делаете кучу `<Border>`, внутри делаете ещё один `<StackPanel>` и уж затем у вас идёт необходимый элемент `<TextBox>`. Зачем вы так все это завернули?
2. Вы видели то, что у вас пишется в `Padding`? У вас везде стоит `Padding="20 180 630 230"` что категорически нельзя делать! Вы к примеру измените размер окна, часть элементов выйдут за границы, добавите ещё какие то элементы, тоже может все съехать. Вы объекты загоняете в дикие рамки и грубо говоря "прибиваете их гвоздями" к вашему окну. Дайте им свободы, укажите один объект, к примеру `<Grid>`, ему укажите нужные поля да колонки, внутри этого `<Grid>` размещайте по нужным местам другие элементы, к примеру  и ему указывайте положение в конкретно этой ячейке (верх, низ, право, лево), делаете отступы (**ну прям максимум** 20, не делайте их 600-1000) и все у вас будет работать как надо! P.S. Отступы такие обычно делает сама студия, если вы двигаете объекты руками в конструкторе, не делайте этого не в коем случае и поберегите свои нервы.

Как должна выглядеть более менее правильная разметка:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Создаем 3 ряда одинакового размера -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Создаем 3 столбца одинакового размера -->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Размещаем объекты -->
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 4" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 6" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 7" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 8" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0" Text="MyText 9" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

В итоге у нас выйдет что то вроде этого (если смотреть через конструктор):

[image: Result]

И заметьте, при изменение окна у вас не будет нечего слетать, давайте объектам чёткие указания того, где он должен находится с помощью `VerticalAlignment` и `HorizontalAlignment`, задавайте минимальные отступы от того положения, где он находится и будет вам счастье. Надеюсь смог растолковать все. Удачи!

Comment: Если нужны одинаковые клетки - можно использовать UniformGrid