# В WPF окно отображается не правильно

Tags: wpf

В WPF я создал кнопку и поместил ее в правый нижний угол.[image: Выглядит сама форма так:]
Запускаю, а выглядит это всё так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И если его растягивать, то кнопку видно, но если размер фиксированный, то никак не растянешь.
Как мне сделать, что бы оно было адекватно.
Код вот такой:

```
<Window x:Class="Parser.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Parser"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="600"
    Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="30" Margin="720,554,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="80"/>


</Grid>
```

Comment: `Margin="720,554,0,0"` - ну не используйте вы дизайнер для размещения элементов...

Comment: А как тогда их размещать? Я просто только начал с WPF разбираться.

Comment: Руками, самостоятельно писать XAML. Научитесь позиционировать объекты, пользоваться `Grid`, `*Panel` элементами. К примеру, ваша кнопка, зачем ей отступ, если можно задать просто `<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Кнопка" />`. Сейчас вы говорите: "Ей, размести мне кнопку в верхнем левом углу, но сделай ей отступ 720 слева, да и сверху 554, чтоб она была в нижнем правом углу", не кажется что-то странным тут? Вон можете глянуть мой древний [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798423/220553), вот это к вам все и относится)

Comment: Я вот всё равно не могу понять, как работает этот дизайнер. Я сделал всё нормально, на дизайнере всё выглядит как я хочу, но при запуске, кнопка немного отрублена.

Comment: Я же вам сказал, забудьте про дизайнер, используйте его только для того, чтоб видеть результат, все, больше он не годен для чего-либо. Не двигайте там и не размещайте через него объекты! Пишите все руками, в XAML разметке, сами, без сторонней помощи. Он легкий, очень.