# Элемент scrollviever в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

я использую элемент scrollviever

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="468,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" Name="ScrollViewer1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  CanContentScroll="True">
        <StackPanel Name="t" Margin="506,52,78,122" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

но при тесте вместо stackpanel (в нем появляются элементы) высвечивается пустой белый scrollviever

Comment: А что вы еще ожидали, устанавливая там отступы в 500 и выше пунктов? Научитесь позиционировать объекты без отступов, будет вам счастье.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть еще пара ссылок-дублей? добавлю

Comment: @aepot Думаю чет из этого можно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798423/220553 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295679/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ думаю даже нужно, добавил, спасибо.